# Create an array based on the keys of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to create an array based on some selection of keys inside an existing constant javascript object

```
const EXISTING_CONSTANT_OBJECT  = {
      'fr': '10',
      'es': '15'
      'us': '10'
      'uk': '7'
      //and so on for many other iso country codes and UNPREDICTABLE key names
}
```

I need to be able to create an array (without modifying `EXISTING_CONSTANT_OBJECT` for immutability reasons) with all keys whose value are equal to `10`.

For example, the expected output is

```
object_to_create_arr = ["fr","us"]
```

I tried using `reduce` but failed.

note: I can use ES6 and usually prefer as it's usually more concise.

Comment: use the method ````let arrayOfKeys = Object.keys( yourObject )````

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez not really, you did not fully read the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` and `filter`

```js
const obj = { 'fr': '10','es': '15','us': '10','uk': '7'}

let final = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => +obj[key] === 10)

console.log(final)
```

Here `+` is used for implicit conversion to number, because in strict equality `'10'` and 10 are not same

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(<object>)` will do the trick
BTW: Your object is invalid. You're missing some commas.

```js
const EXISTING_CONSTANT_OBJECT = {
  'fr': '10',
  'es': '15',
  'us': '10',
  'uk': '7'
  //and so on for many other iso country codes and UNPREDICTABLE key names
};

const keys = Object.keys(EXISTING_CONSTANT_OBJECT);
console.log(keys);
```

If you want to just get the keys where the value is 10, it's just as simple as adding `.filter`

```js
const EXISTING_CONSTANT_OBJECT = {
  'fr': '10',
  'es': '15',
  'us': '10',
  'uk': '7'
};

const keysWith10 = Object.keys(EXISTING_CONSTANT_OBJECT).filter(k => EXISTING_CONSTANT_OBJECT[k] === '10');
console.log(keysWith10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with `reduce`. As mentioned with other answers, you can also use `filter` (which might actually be better).

Here is a solution using `reduce`

```js
const obj  = {
  'fr': '10',
  'es': '15',
  'us': '10',
  'uk': '7'
}

let result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (parseInt(obj[curr], 10) === 10) {
    acc.push(curr)
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks i really hesitated between your solution and @code maniac but his one is more concise and equally correct

Comment: no problem, they both achieve the same result! Just wanted to show how it can be done with `reduce`

Comment: Sure, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function createArr(obj){
    let arr = [];
    for (let key in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && String(obj[key]) === '10') arr.push(key);
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys()` function returns the array of values corresponding to the keys of object you feed to this function. For example:

```
let yourObject = { key1: value1, key2: value2, key3:value3}
let arr = Object.keys(yourObject)
console.log(arr) // Output: [ 'key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

Hope this helps!!